# A better way of handling Module output?

Tags: function-construction, scoping, save

I am sure this has been asked before in a way or another. I need to `Save` or `DumpSave` some symbols that contain the result of some processing.

Currently my code has a low level function that does the dirty work, and a high level one that is a handy proxy to call the low level one.

Here is how my code schematically works:

```
   LowLevelFunction[ba_] := Module[{res},
    Table[res[elem] = 
    If[ToString[ba] == "yes", X, 2 X], {elem, {one, two}}];
   res]

  HighLevelFunction[a_] := Module[{res}, res = LowLevelFunction[a]; res]
```

Then I use these functions as:

```
  Processed[yes] = HighLevelFunction[yes]
  Processed[maybe] = HighLevelFunction[maybe]
```

At this point  `?Processed` returns `Processed[maybe]=res$2748` and `Processed[yes]=res$2745`. I am happy with this so far because I can evaluate in the current notebook and get the answer that I want

```
   Processed[yes][one]
   Processed[maybe][two]

   Out[270]= X

   Out[271]= 2 X
```

Furthermore when I do  `Save["~/fileprocessed.mx", Processed]` I get a mx file that contains a reference to `res$2748` and `res$2745` *and* the actual symbols `res$2748` and `res$2745`. Therefore I can do `Get["~/fileprocessed.mx"]` on a new notebook and a new kernel and

```
    Processed[yes][one]
    Processed[maybe][two]
```

will give me the right output.

Now my question is if there is a better way of handling this. For instance a way that avoid  having to use Temporary objects, that, for instance, would not be saved if I use `DumpSave` instead of `Save`.

Answer (score 6):

Generate and export `Unique` variables from `LowLevelFunction`.

```
LowLevelFunction[ba_] := Module[{res}, res = Unique["res"]; 
  Table[res[elem] = If[ToString[ba] == "yes", X, 2 X], {elem, {one, two}}]; res]
```

These variables are not temporary, and you should be able to save them

Answer (score 3):

First thing to note is that your `HighLevelFunction` is not relevant here. When it's evaluated, `res` variable, inside `Module`, evaluates to result of `LowLevelFunction` call.

`res$...` symbols you're seeing are coming from `Module` in your `LowLevelFunction`. In this module you're saving your calculation results as `DownValues` of temporary module variable `res`.

If you use Mathematica v10, then instead of auxiliary symbol with `DownValues`, you can use an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

```
ClearAll[LowLevelFunction, HighLevelFunction]

LowLevelFunction[ba_] := 
    Association[Table[elem -> If[ToString[ba] == "yes", X, 2 X], {elem, {one, two}}]]

HighLevelFunction[a_] := Module[{res}, res = LowLevelFunction[a]; res]
```

By calling `HighLevelFunction` with redefined `LowLevelFunction` we get:

```
Processed[yes] = HighLevelFunction[yes]
(* <|one -> X, two -> X|> *)
Processed[maybe] = HighLevelFunction[maybe]
(* <|one -> 2 X, two -> 2 X|> *)
```

You can access values, associated with certain keys, like in your original implementation:

```
Processed[yes][one]
(* X *)
Processed[maybe][two]
(* 2X *)
```

You can use `Save` and `DumpSave` and everything will work as expected.